# How to make a linked collection into an appended asset?

Tags: collections, append

If I have linked a collection in my Blend file and now I want it to behave like I appended it... how would I do that?

The collection in question contains many mesh objects. I have also parented the linked collection to an empty in my master file so I can move it around.

Comment: It seams that "Make Proxy" does not work if the collection has been parented to an empty...

Answer (score 1):

- Hover over the collection in the outliner.
- Click the right mouse button to bring up the Collection menu.
- Go to *ID_Data*.
- Select *Make Local*
  [image: Collection Menu showing Make Local Option]